"Investment Optimization"
I am trying to figure out the following problem.
I own a machine, which generates $1 per second. There are 100 other machines:

A. makes your revenue 2x bigger, costs $20

B. makes your revenue 6x bigger, costs $50

C. makes your revenue 2x bigger, costs $50

....


The goal is to maximize the total generated money after 1,000,000 seconds (ignore costs). Which machines should I buy and when?
I should clearly buy B before C, as B offers a bigger increase for the same price. But at the beginning, should I wait 20 seconds to buy A, or wait 50 seconds to buy B?
Possible solutions could be permutations of 100 machines, such that at each point, I am saving money for the first machine in the list, and after buying it, I save for a next one, and so on.
My idea is to "simulate each permutation" to get the best solution, but there are 100! permutations :(
Is there a name for this kind of problem in Math? Is there an algorithm for solving it?
Also, if each new machine produces X USD per second instead of increasing the total revenue, would it be the same problem?

The rules are not clear.  Does each machine operate only once or can we reuse it?  If we can reuse them. must we pay a use fee?  Do the machines take time to run?  Can multiple machines run simultaneously?  Not to mention that we don't know about the other $97$ machines....

As to the delays, I don't understand how you could avoid them.  Can't buy $C$ without having $$50$ so we need to wait at least $50$ seconds.  And, in that scenario, we'd have no funds to increase.

The original machine "spits out" 1 dollar each second, and other machines increase the revenue of that original machine (from the moment of buying, forever).

Assume that we have current income of $a$, and want to buy two machines, one with price $x_1$ and multiplier $y_1$, and other with price $x_2$ and multiplier $y_2$. What is the optimal order? Obviously, the one that allows us to buy both faster (as right after buying the second machine in both cases we will have the same income - $a y_1 y_2$ and the same amount of money - $0$, so the only thing that affects final amount of money is how fast we get there).
If we buy the first machine first, the second later, we need time $\frac{x_1}{a} + \frac{x_2}{y_1 a}$. Vice versa we need $\frac{x_2}{a} + \frac{x_1}{y_2 a}$. It's better to get the first machine before the second if
$$\frac{x_1}{a} + \frac{x_2}{y_1 a} < \frac{x_2}{a} + \frac{x_1}{y_2 a}$$
$$\frac{x_1 y_1}{y_1 - 1} < \frac{x_2 y_2}{y_2 - 1}$$
(assuming $x_1, x_2 > 0$, $y_1, y_2 > 1$)
Lets call $\frac{xy}{y - 1}$ "PE" of machine. If we have some order of buying machines, and it's not sorted by PE, we can improve final result by finding two machines in order where we buy higher PE right before lower PE, and swapping them.
Assume the last machine bought has characteristics $x_2, y_2$, when second to last machine was bought time remained was $t$ and income was $a$, and there was also non-bought machine with characteristics $x_1, y_1$ with lower PE. Lets prove that it would be not worse to either buy both, or not buy anything - ie in optimal solution we buy all machines with lower PE before higher.
If we buy nothing, we get $at$ at the end. If we buy the second we get $\left(t - \frac{x_2}{a}\right)\cdot y_2 a$, and if we buy both we get $\left(t - \frac{x_1}{a} - \frac{x_2}{ay_1}\right)\cdot a y_1 y_2$. So, if buying second was optimal choice, we get $$\begin{cases}
\left(t - \frac{x_2}{a}\right)\cdot y_2 a > ta\\
\left(t - \frac{x_2}{a}\right)\cdot y_2 a > \left(t - \frac{x_1}{a} - \frac{x_2}{ay_1}\right)\cdot a y_1 y_2
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
ta > \frac{x_2 y_2}{y_2 - 1}\\
ta < \frac{x_1 y_1}{y_1 - 1} \end{cases}$$
However, this contradicts assumption that first machine has lower PE than the second one.
So, in optimal strategy, we buy $k$ machines with the lowest PE in ascending order. We can find the best solution by sorting machines by PE, iterating over them and checking if buying next machine improves final result.

That's a perfect explanation! My real case is a bit more complciated: I have N machines, producing 1 dollar per second. I have M "upgrades". Each upgrade costs a specific amount, and has a multiplier for a specific machine. Some upgrades apply to all machines.
Can I solve it step by step, and in each step, choose the upgrade "greedily"? At each step, I would compute the total current income, and would find the current multiplier and the current PE of each upgrade, and would choose the upgrade with the lowest PE?

I am not even sure how to define PE wiht multiple machines. And it's definetely more complicated now: if, for example, you have a lot of "good" upgrades for different machines, and "mediocre" upgrades for the same, it can easily be better to buy "mediocre" - so, unlike single machine case, you can't decide which of two upgrades is better now without looking at others.

At a certain point, I can tell that a specific upgrade would multiply the performance of a 3rd machine by 5, but I can compare the total performance before and after the upgrade, and see that it would grow 1.3 times. Can I use this to compute the PE "of this state" to choose the best upgrade at that point?

The problem is that if you have one upgrade of the first machine with price 10 and efficiency 2, and one of the second with price 10.00001 and efficiency 2, you are better to start with the first one. However, if the second upgrade is available in two copies, you better start with it. So, even at given point, there is no ordering of upgrades s.t. you should choose the best upgrade by this ordering regardless of what else is available as long as it's not better. I have suspicion that many machines problem can be NP hard, but don't have any ideas for proof yet.
